# Как обновить права пользователя в запущенной программе?

Tags: c#, firebird

Есть программа на c#, работающая с базой Firebird. Как я понимаю, при подключении запоминаются права пользователя на момент подключения и заново не считываются. Т.е. если дать пользователю какие-то новые права на действия с БД, то он их получит только после того, как перезагрузит программу. 
Теперь сам вопрос: есть ли какая-либо возможность пользователю считать заново права из БД, не перезагружаясь?

Comment: Смотрите документацию к адаптеру базы данных. А вообще, я бы предположил, что достаточно переподключиться.

Comment: Переподключиться пробовал, не помогло, обновление получается только при перезапуске программы.  
Документацию посмотрю, спасибо.  
Если у кого-то есть свои предложения, напишите, буду рад.

Comment: Хм. А как вы переподключаетесь? База данных-то не может знать, из какого приложения к ней стучатся — из того же или нет. Так что есть шанс, что вы что-то недопереподключили.

Comment: да банально: есть переменная Dtb типа FbConnection. делаю Dtb.Close(), а затем Dtb.Open().
Этот метод применяю для восстановления соединения с БД после обрыва.

Comment: Да, строки FbConnection.ClearPool(Dtb); Dtb = new FbConnection(con); помогли.  
Спасибо большое, VladD.

Comment: Пожалуйста! Оформил как ответ.

Answer (score 1):

Возможно, подключение кеширует права на стороне пользователя. Попробуйте переподключиться к базе: закройте старый и заведите *новый* `FbConnection`. Может быть ещё нужно сказать `FbConnection.ClearPool`.